# Callback to Async Await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have been trying to use this library: https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor

example from there:

```
new ImageCompressor(file, {
    quality: .6,
    success(result) {
      ...
    },
    error(e) {
      ...
    },
  });
```

I want to wrap this function inside an async function called compress to use it like:

```
const compressed file = await compress(file)
```

Comment: And what did you tried...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  function compress(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       new ImageCompressor(file, {
         quality: .6,
         success: resolve,
         error: reject
      });
   });
 }
```

Comment: @ele jup, i dont think that future readers will profit from this.

Answer (score 4):

You can simple wrap the function like this:

```
  function compress(parameters) {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        new ImageCompressor(file, {
          quality: .6,
          success(result) {
            resolve(result)
          },
          error(e) {
            reject(e)
          },
        });
     })
```